# Slow query on Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, jedis, amazon-elasticache

While running the command to list the slow queries on redis client(aws elasticache)

```
 SLOWLOG GET 128
```

I am seeing queries

```
CLIENT LIST
```

They are taking ~12 seconds to run.

We are not calling these queries from our code. Any suggestions on how I can find the reason for their execution?

Comment: What library are you using to connect to Redis? Maybe it was that library?